# (C#) BackgroundWorker() ProgressChanged not working

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a **WPF** application that consist of two threads simulating an enterprise producting and selling items in 52 weeks (only one transaction is allowed per week). I need to use a background worker as well so that I can display the data in a listview. As of right now, my UI freezes when clicking on `simulate` but I can see that the output is still working in the debugging terminal. I have tried everything that I can think of and to be honest, I have had the help of my teacher and even he couldn't find a working solution.

---

1. What is freezing my UI when I call `Simulate()` ?
2. When my code is different and my UI isn't freezing, my listview never updates because it seems that `DataProgress()` doesn't work — `e.UserStart` is never iterating.

---

**Simulate button calls :**

```cs
private void Simulate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Declare BackgroundWorker
    Data = new ObservableCollection<Operations>();
    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(52);

    worker.DoWork += ShowData;
    worker.ProgressChanged += DataProgress;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += DataToDB;

    Production = new Production(qtyProduction, timeExecProd);
    Sales = new Sales(qtySales, timeExecSales);

    Thread prod = new Thread(Production.Product);
    prod.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(100);

    Thread sales = new Thread(Sales.Sell);
    sales.Start();
}
```

**DoWork : ShowData() :**

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Simulation started | Initial stock : 500");

Production = new Production(qtyProduction, timeExecProd);
Sales = new Sales(qtySales, timeExecSales);

while (Factory.Week < max) // max = 52 
{
    if (worker.CancellationPending) // also this isn't reacting to worker.CancelAsync();
        e.Cancel = true;

   // My teacher tried to call my threads from here, but it breaks the purpose of having 
   // two threads as he was just calling 52 times two functions back to back and therefore
   // wasn't "randomizing" the transactions.

    int progressPercentage = Convert.ToInt32(((double)(Factory.Week) / max) * 100);
    (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(progressPercentage, Factory.Week);
}
```

**ProgressChanged : DataProgress() :**

```cs
if (e.UserState != null) // While using debugger, it looks like this is called over & over
{
    Data.Add(new Operations() 
    {
        id = rnd.Next(1,999),
        name = Factory.name,
        qtyStock = Factory.Stock,
        averageStock = Factory.AverageStock,
        week = Factory.Week
    });
    listview.ItemsSource = Data;
}
```

**RunWorkerCompleted : DataToDB() :**

```cs
    // Outputs "Work done" for now.
```

---

In case you want to know what happens when I call my threads, it looks like this :

**Sell() :**

```cs
while (Factory.Week <= 52)
{
    lock (obj)
    {
        // some math function callings¸
        Factory.Week++;
    }
    Thread.Sleep(timeExecSales);
}
```

---

Should I use a third thread just for updating my listview? I don't see how as I need it to be synced with my static variables. *This is my first project for learning multithreading...* I'm kind of clueless and flabbergasted that even my teacher can't help.

Comment: As posted, the while-loop never terminates.  It slams the UI thread at a very high rate, millions of times per second.  That's very expensive code as well, it makes the UI thread burn 100% core and never able to catch up.  The side-effect is that it doesn't get around to doing its normal duties anymore, repainting the window and responding to input.  Given how wrong this is, best to get drastic.  Instead generate a List of result in DoWork and use RunWorkerCompleted to update the ItemsSource.

Comment: Just looking at your code, don't tell the background worker to start running before you hook up all the events.  Also, just changing the ItemSource on a control won't force it to refresh.  At the very least, you should probably be calling DataBind on your listview, and possibly calling refresh/repaint.

Comment: And as stacy mentioned.. change `while (Factory.Week < max)` to `while (Factory.Week < max && !worker.CancellationPending)`

Comment: Other issues notwithstanding, you should be using Tasks for this. One of my favorite programming quotes is from Stephen Cleary's "Concurrency in C# Cookbook": "*As soon as you type new Thread(), it’s over; your project already has legacy code.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, there isnt enough context in the code posted to get a full picture to answer your questions *accurately*. We can, however, deduce what is going wrong just from the code you have posted.

First, lets try to answer your two questions. We can likely infer the following:

This code here:

```
if (e.UserState != null) 
{
    Data.Add(new Operations() 
    {
        id = rnd.Next(1,999),
        name = Factory.name,
        qtyStock = Factory.Stock,
        averageStock = Factory.AverageStock,
        week = Factory.Week
    });
    listview.ItemsSource = Data;
}
```

You are using a Windows Forms background thread object to try and update a WPF GUI object which should only be done on the main GUI thread. There is also the obvious no-no of never updating GUI objects from non-UI threads. Using `BackgroundWorker` also has its own issues with threading (foreground/background), contexts and execution, as it relies on the `Dispatcher` and `SynchronizationContexts` to get the job done.

Then there is the curiosity of setting the binding over and over in this line:

`listview.ItemsSource = Data;`

Let's put a pin in that for a moment...

There is, as the other commenter pointer out already, no exit strategy in your while loop:

```
while (Factory.Week < max) // max = 52 
{
    if (worker.CancellationPending) // also this isn't reacting to worker.CancelAsync();
        e.Cancel = true;

   // My teacher tried to call my threads from here, but it breaks the purpose of having 
   // two threads as he was just calling 52 times two functions back to back and therefore
   // wasn't "randomizing" the transactions.

    int progressPercentage = Convert.ToInt32(((double)(Factory.Week) / max) * 100);
    (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(progressPercentage, Factory.Week);
}
```

But thats not the bigger problem... in addition to the misuse/misunderstanding of when/how many/how to use threading, there doesnt seem to be any kind of thread synchronization of any kind. There is no way to predict or track thread execution of lifetime in this way.

At this point the question is technically more or less answered, but I feel like this will just leave you more frustrated and no better off than you started. So maybe a quick crash course in basic design might help straighten out this mess, something your teacher should have done.

Assuming you are pursuing software development, and since you have chosen WPF here as your "breadboard" so to speak, you will likely come across terms such as MVC (model view controller) or MVVM (model view view-model). You will also likely come across design principles such as SOLID, separation of concerns, and grouping things into services.

Your code here is a perfect example of why all of these frameworks and principles exist. Lets look at some of the problems you have encountered and how to fix them:

1. You have threading code (logic and services - controller [loosely speaking]) mixed in with presentation code (listview update - view) and collection update (your observable collection - model). Thats one reason (of many) you are having such a difficult time coding, fixing and maintaining the problem at hand. To clean it up, separate it out (separation of concerns). You might even move each operation into its own class with an interface/API to that class (service/ micro-service).
2. Not everything needs to be solved with threads. But for now, lets learn to crawl, then walk before we run. Before you start learning about async/await or the TPL (task parallel library) lets go old school. Get a good book... something even from 20 years ago is find... go old school, and learn how to use the ThreadPool and kernel synchronization objects such as mutexes, events, etc and how to signal between threads. Once you master that, then learn about TPL and async/await.
3. Dont cross the streams. Dont mix WinForms, WPF and I even saw `Console.WriteLine`.
4. Learn about Data Binding, and in particular how it works in WPF. `ObservableCollection` is your friend, bind your `ItemsSource` to it ***once***, then update the `ObservableCollection` and leave the GUI object alone.

Hopefully this will help you straighten out the code and get things running.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your time and detailed answer. I do not understand how to use threads properly because it is the first task that my teacher is giving us. He also just introduced us to MVC so there's not much knowledge on that part either. I've been using MVC in Java but I feel like it's harder to use when doing a project in WPF which adds another layer on top of all that new stuff that I have to implement.

Comment: My application is just a simulator that calculates how many items I produce in my factory and how many I sell. Only one transaction can occur per week. I have used a static variable and the `lock` so that only one thread can access it at a time. Also, while my threads are doing it 52 times, I need to update the listview on real time but of course If I do so in the main thread, my application will be left frozen. That is why I have tried adding a backgroundworker and hoped that my `while` loop would end once it reaches the max value (52). My iteration should work but indeed the while loop is

Comment: running way to fast and is not synced with the threads. I just don't know how to build such an application and my teacher fails to teach us properly... I simply have a class Factory with static variables. Then I have `Production` and `Sales` class that are my threads.

Comment: Two thoughts: First looking into Interlocked.Increment, you can avoid `lock` altogether, see this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=netframework-4.8
Second, look into lockless techniques, or at the very least single writer multiple readers. You should really avoid using the `lock` statement, at least the way you are using it (create a singleton static object to lock if you must use it).

Comment: I have slept on it and read some of the notes that my teacher gave us. He also came back to me about how to solve the code in its actual state and I wanted to know your opinion before drastically changing the code. He proposed that I should edit my `Production` and `Sales` classes to be `BackgroundWorkers`. I could then just return the results of the progress into a model and change my view with the main (WPF) thread. I suppose I would some kind of loop in need another thread to periodically check the new results to return to the main thread?

Comment: Also, I am doing more than just incrementing a static variable in my `lock` blocks. I'm calculating the average, the taxes, the total production, generating an ID for my database, etc. I have read on some other post in SO that if I needed more than just incrementing a static variable, I would need to use `lock`.

Comment: My suspicion is that your teacher has limited experience designing real world systems. If he/she did, they would know that BackgroundWorkers is actually based on AsyncOperation which uses the Dispatcher and SynchronizationContexts to achieve it's goals, which abstracts the whole notion of just threading itself. I think you should approach coding Production and Sales as services that communicate with the GUI in a decoupled way, be it by threading IPC (synchronization objects) or messages (contexts). That is the key to MVC and makes the solution portable from a WPF implementation.

Comment: Take a look at this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/9hk12d4y(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I would also take a look a Stephen Cleary's articles on multi-tasking, and why you should probably eschew the use of `BackgroundWorker` for your project. A good jumping off point would be here:
Various Implementations of Asynchronous Background Tasks
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html